# Curious dependency resolution error

Tags: c#, compiler-errors

I've recently encountered a dependecy resolution error that I'm hoping someone here can explain.

I have an interface defined in a 3rdparty assembly (`I3rdParty`), one "common" assembly that's depends on that assembly and a "client" library that depends on the "common" assembly.
Let's call them, 3rdparty.dll, common.dll and client.dll.

The client.dll should not have a dependency to the 3rdparty.dll.

in common.dll the following was defined:

```
public static class Factory
{
    public static object Create(I3rdParty ifc) { ... }
    public static object Create(string value1, string value2, long? value3 = null) { ... }
}
```

One of the factory methods was used from the client.dll like:

```
var instance = Factory.Create("SomeValue", "SomeValue2");
```

At this point everything worked as expected.

Then a bool parameter was introduced to the first factory method in common.dll so it became:

```
public static object Create(I3rdParty ifc, bool value) { ... }
```

Then the build of client.dll started failing due to a missing dependency to 3rdparty.dll, e.g:

```
The type 'I3rdParty' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced...
```

I'm assuming that this has something to do with that the methods now accepts the same number of parameters (since the second Create method's third parameter defaults to null).

But I thought that it would still be able to select the correct Create method based on the type of the parameters. Can anyone explain the reason for the behavior I'm seeing?

Comment: Interesting. Do you experience the same error if you add `Create(string)` (in the state before you added the bool value)?

Comment: On another note, if your `Create(I3rdParty)` method is never intended to be used by your `client.dll` why not make it `internal` instead of `public`?

Comment: Yes, but only if I were to change the client.dll to use that Create method.

And Yes, based on the example above that would probably be my first though as well :)
In the actual scenario where I encountered this though, both create methods were internal and InternalsVisibleTo was set to the client.dll, but I felt that was besides the point of the question.
The code above is from a simplified isolated repro of the error.
Solving the compiler error is a non-issue, was merely hoping someone could explain the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you added a `bool` parameter to the first overload, the compiler has now to check **for two possible method signatures** to choose the one that should be used (this is the *overload resolution*).

You're calling `Create(string, string)`

With two parameters, you have the following overloads available:

```
Create(I3rdParty, bool)
Create(string, string)
```

Obviously only the second one can match (as a `string` cannot be implicitly converted to `bool` for the second parameter), but it appears the compiler is not clever enough and *has to know what exactly `I3rdParty` is* (which means it requires the reference to the assembly that defines it), before being able to determine the `(I3rdParty, bool)` overload wasn't an option.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, if I understand correctly, to handle this generically the compiler needs full type information of all parameters in all possible overloads in order to make an informed decision,  
due to implicit conversions and whatnot. i.e: this is something that theoretically could be handled by the compiler, but might be impractical just to cover an edge case.